# How do I convert my recorded voice to text in a file?

Tags: software-recommendation, sound-recorder

I need a TALK to TEXT program  to speak to the computer and have it write my reports. I have problems with my wrist and can not type fast. I'm working with the Linux system. I need a link to install this also. please help  i can't find what i need

Answer (score 3):

You can find the following available from the Software Centre:

## [Simon](http://simon-listens.blogspot.pt/)

> Simon is an open-source speech recognition program and replaces the mouse and
> keyboard.  It is in development for physically disabled people and
> seniors to give them the possibility to chat, to write e-mails, to
> surf the internet, to do internet-banking and much more. It is
> designed to be very flexible and allows customization for any
> application where speech recognition is needed.